# How can I get a hold of a large collection of varied I.P. addresses?

Tags: vps, honeypot

I want to get a low cost host (i.e. a cheap VPS Server) that has a lot of I.P. addresses pointed at it. This is for the purpose of running a honeypot server, the more I.P.s the more hits it will get.

Is anyone aware of a host that could provide such a service?

Comment: The problem is, almost all hosts try their based to avoid being the target of attacks.  If you run a honey pot then your honey pot might  be the reason hackers started investigating other hosts on that network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the relative scarcity of IPv4 addresses, I'd guess that you'll have a hard time finding a host that will be willing to part with "a lot of IP addresses". From what I've been able to gather, most people who are running honeypot servers are associated with either Universities or other organizations that have access to a large IP space to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be almost impossible to get "varied" IP addresses for a single host.  An ISP providing VPS services is going to have a block of IP addresses on the same subnet assigned to the machine hosting the VPS instances.  You could get a few IPs, but they'll be contiguous.

Also, it's unlikely the ISP will appreciate you running a honeypot on the VPS, especially if it's not set up correctly and hackers end up using it to attack other hosts on the ISP's network or the general Internet.

Why not run the honeypot off of your home Internet connection?  Set up your router to route all packets to a single machine on your internal network.  You could even route them to a virtual machine running under VMware on one of your other systems.

If you really want to have honeypots on multiple IPs, you should just get multiple VPS instances with different ISPs.